# How to debug javascript in xcode 4.0.2?

Tags: javascript, debugging, xcode4

I want to run the simulator and when it is running, debug my javascript code that is launching the pages.

Is it possible?

If not possible, then can log something?

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
You can not debug at moment. maybe in future.
You can use third party tools or you can develop your internal debug tool.
web inspector remote, weinre is best for mac developers.
Also there are different tools on net.